# How to get total value over previous objects of the same class in Django?

Tags: python, django

I wrote my own billing software in Django. In that I have a model called bills. Every bill has a price value. Now I want to give the bill model a function that adds up the price values of all previous bills and the current one. This function is meant to give me a number of how much I've earned so far.

But every time I try to implement it I run into the problem that I can't use the bill class within the definition of itself.

What is the best approach to add a function to my bill class that gets all the bill objects (including the current one) and adds up the price values?

Comment: Are you storing bills in a database, using the Django ORM? If so, use the ORM to query the DB to get all bills: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/.

Comment: But if I do Rechnung.objects.filter(nummer>=self.nummer) (nummer is an id, Rechnung means bill) within the Bill class it says that nummer is not defined. Outside of this class the code works as expected.

Comment: See my comment, use `nummer__gte = self.nummer`. This is evaluated at runtime, so if you have set the nummer field to a value, you should not see this error.

Comment: If you need more help, please update your Q with a simplified version of what you have tried.

Comment: @JasonTS Instead of this `Rechnung.objects.filter(nummer>=self.nummer)`, you have to write something like this, `Rechnung.objects.filter(nummer__gte = self.nummer)`. Remember, Django is no different than regular Python: a method call (like `filter`) takes ordinary keyword-style arguments: in this case, the key is `nummer__gte` and the value is `self.nummer`. The key effectively uses a special Django syntax to tell the ORM you want to compare each Rechnung's nummer attribute against the value you pass, using the `>=` operator.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sensing that I've misunderstood something, but why don't you just do something like this?

```
class Bill(models.Model):
    due_date = models.DateField()
    price = models.IntegerField()
    paid = models.BooleanField()

    def get_previous_bills(self):
        return Bill.objects.filter(due_date__lte=timezone.now(), paid=True)

    def get_total_price(self):
        return sum(p.price for p in self.get_previous_bills())
```

Comment: You should probably use Manager in this case and have get_previous_bills function inside that manager. Then you can use self.objects.filter(due_date__lte=timezone.now(), paid=True) and call Bill.objects.get_previous_bills()

Comment: @MarioGudelj Interesting - I'm quite new to Django, so I haven't played much around with custom managers. What is the advantage of using managers for this over static methods?